# Python : Creating raw ECC-ECDSA-SECP256R1 private(32-bytes) and public(64-bytes) keys

Tags: python, python-cryptography

I want to generate raw 32-bytes private key and raw 64-bytes public key (ECC-SECP256R1) using Python.
Which library should I install in my Python 3.7 and what APIs do I call to be able to generate raw keys?
Please help.
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The [ECDSA](https://pypi.org/project/ecdsa/) library can do this.

Generate a key pair:

```
import ecdsa

sk = ecdsa.SigningKey.generate(curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1) 
vk = sk.get_verifying_key()

# Your byte values will vary, each time you generate().  Here is an example pair.

skBytes = sk.to_string()
print(f"Signing key = {[b  for b in skBytes]}")
# [242, 122, 66, 46, 189, 185, 103, 40, 162, 156, 155, 213, 77, 38, 251, 23, 148, 207, 49, 206, 122, 63, 117, 150, 196, 115, 82, 203, 95, 104, 60, 227]

vkBytes = vk.to_string()
print(f"Verifying key = {[b  for b in vkBytes]}")
# [31, 164, 220, 214, 106, 22, 45, 112, 244, 49, 124, 250, 217, 209, 51, 83, 161, 239, 137, 124, 25, 220, 112, 116, 80, 9, 64, 130, 9, 27, 92, 198, 123, 146, 213, 154, 142, 148, 90, 6, 142, 177, 31, 151, 215, 9, 216, 36, 51, 27, 222, 224, 132, 7, 39, 227, 48, 31, 244, 218, 206, 59, 249, 196]
```

The key pair can be restored from bytes:

```
skBytes = bytes([242, 122, 66, 46, 189, 185, 103, 40, 162, 156, 155, 213, 77, 38, 251, 23, 148, 207, 49, 206, 122, 63, 117, 150, 196, 115, 82, 203, 95, 104, 60, 227])
vkBytes = bytes([31, 164, 220, 214, 106, 22, 45, 112, 244, 49, 124, 250, 217, 209, 51, 83, 161, 239, 137, 124, 25, 220, 112, 116, 80, 9, 64, 130, 9, 27, 92, 198, 123, 146, 213, 154, 142, 148, 90, 6, 142, 177, 31, 151, 215, 9, 216, 36, 51, 27, 222, 224, 132, 7, 39, 227, 48, 31, 244, 218, 206, 59, 249, 196])
sk = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(skBytes, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
vk = ecdsa.VerifyingKey.from_string(vkBytes, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
# or vk = sk.get_verifying_key()
```

Example signing and verifying:

```
message = b"Hello, world!"
signature = sk.sign(message)
print(f"{[b  for b in signature]}")
# [161, 22, 110, 48, 232, 36, 152, 153, 22, 7, 177, 219, 157, 102, 237, 57, 243, 216, 186, 207, 22, 168, 170, 247, 216, 235, 160, 13, 35, 37, 141, 237, 63, 50, 84, 31, 203, 95, 212, 91, 13, 150, 156, 125, 255, 197, 30, 133, 193, 174, 129, 174, 192, 33, 90, 160, 243, 78, 96, 92, 38, 1, 237, 129]
isSignatureValid = vk.verify(signature, message)
print(f"{isSignatureValid=}")
# isSignatureValid=True
```

Credit to this question for introducing me to the ecdsa package:
[ECDSA Signing and Verifying issue between python ECDSA and C micro-ecc library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56142232/ecdsa-signing-and-verifying-issue-between-python-ecdsa-and-c-micro-ecc-library)

Comment: The user requested secp256r1 and you provided help code for secp256k1. The ECDSA packages obviously does not support recp256r1.

Comment: See: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33052/is-there-any-difference-between-nist-and-secp-curves-in-terms-of-their-algorithm -- NIST256p is equivalent to secp256r1 and is supported in python ecdsa